# MBP no audio at all

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

My MBP internal audio suddenly started making a really unexpected static noise and then silenced, the audio stopped working, the headphone port also does not work. If I shutdown this computer for a while the audio seems to work again (for a while then the noise repeats and audio shuts down). The OS doesn't recognise any audio outputs, i.e. the icon at the taskbar is grayed out. If I plug an HDMI on and audio capable device (receiver, monitor) it works with video only, the audio over HDMI option isn't presented and does not work. Bluetooth audio works. I haven't tried hooking a USB "sound card" yet.

I'm surprised HDMI audio did not work, perhaps it shares the same hardware controller? Could this be a software bug?

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
2,2 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

macOS 10.14.6 (18G9323)
```

EDIT:
I have tried reseting NVRAM and SMC

Comment: It sounds an awfully lot like the part of the Mac's hardware that processes sound is near death. That it works a little at first boot and then goes away and is not available from *ANY* output would put the nail in that coffin for me.

Comment: Have you try doing Reset SMC: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 and Reset NVRAM : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063 ?

Comment: Have you looked for output in the Console.app when the audio output is failing? It might contain useful information on what's going on.

Comment: After you reboot, have you measured precisely how much time it takes for the audio to stop working? Is it constant across reboots or random?

Comment: Added a comment re SMC/NVRAM, will try to reproduce the failure, I think I have to let it idle (powered off) for a good while - i've only done it once since it started failing as i dont usually turn it off